# E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-cv-camera

Tags: ros, ros2, 3d-object-recognition, packages, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried solution from @javisshultz

https://answers.ros.org/question/345764/e-unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-desktop-full-or-ros-melodic-desktop/

> echo "deb
> http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list

> sudo apt update

but unfortunately, after last cmd I keep getting

> The repository
> 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu
> jammy Release' does not have a Release
> file.

What can I do more ?

My system :
Ubuntu 22.04
Humble Hawksbill

What is my goal -> image recognition using this node
https://github.com/qboticslabs/rostensorflow

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401825/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-humble-cv-camera/) by [Orpiczy](https://answers.ros.org/users/103849/orpiczy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be trying to use the ROS 1 package repository to install a ROS 2 package.

That doesn't work.

According to [ros2/rolling/Installation: Ubuntu (Debian)](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html#setup-sources), the ROS 2 repository would be `http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu`, not `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu`.

I would suggest to verify you've correctly setup the ROS 2 repositories and followed the installation tutorial.

This is the same problem as in your other #q399935.

> I tried solution from @javisshultz #q345764

the Q&A you link discusses a ROS 1 problem. It's not applicable to ROS 2.

Additionally:

> Unable to locate package ros-humble-cv-camera

According to [status_page/ros_humble_default.html?q=camera](http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_humble_default.html?q=camera), `cv_camera` is not available in ROS 2 Humble.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wenchao](https://answers.ros.org/users/137395/wenchao/) on 2023-04-14**:
I tried to solve the problem by repeating the curl and echo commands in the installation tutorial (https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html), but to no avail.
When I run "sudo apt-get install ros-$(rosversion -d)-turtlesim", it fails to fetch. When I run "sudo apt-get update", one of the lines reads "E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file."

**Comment by [wenchao](https://answers.ros.org/users/137395/wenchao/) on 2023-04-15**:
The answer from https://answers.ros.org/question/402151/the-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file/ worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, check the [ROS Index](https://index.ros.org/packages/) or type `apt search ros-distro` in your linux terminal to determine whether the ros-package is available for your ros-distro. Then, type `sudo apt-get install ros-distro-package_name` to install that package. After that, you can verify that the package has been installed by typing `sudo apt-get rospack list-names` or sudo apt-get rospack list`to show the directory of the installed package. To check if it's up-to-date, type`sudo apt update`to download the latest version of the package.

**In your case, package cv_camera is not supported for [ros-humble](https://index.ros.org/search/?term=cv_camera) yet.**

~Gundam Out.`

---

Originally posted by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) with karma: 81 on 2022-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-03**:
The main problem reported by the OP is caused by the misconfiguration of the ROS package repositories.

You cannot install a `ros-humble-...` package from the ROS 1 package repositories. Regardless of whether it's released or not.

**Comment by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) on 2022-06-03**:
Yeah, I know that but when I typed this response, I was just trying to add on to your comment if the user ends up encountering an issue with installing a package even though the user installed from the correct ROS # package repository.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-03**:
I'd at least mention #q320046 in that case.

**Comment by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) on 2022-06-03**:
Noted, I will keep in mind next time since I'm new to this community wiki. My bad.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-04**:
There is no need to apologise.

**Comment by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) on 2022-06-04**:
this might not be the right place to ask, but do you have any tips on getting good at debugging? I get that it all comes down to being practical at the end of the day but I would like to know if there are other ways that would help too.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-04**:
I'm not sure I understand your comment.

"Debugging" in what way specifically?

**Comment by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) on 2022-06-04**:
learning how to solve errors and knowing what error is the problem

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-06-05**:
Solving problems people have posted on ROS Answers ;)

But in reality: it's just experience.

Working with the tools/code/programs/infrastructure yourself, etc.

**Comment by [qilin_gundamenjoyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/105678/qilin_gundamenjoyer/) on 2022-06-05**:
I lack the experience but I will try. I really want to get good with Robotics so yeah, thanks for the advice!